# iOS Action app extension with transparent background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios-app-extension

I’m trying to make an iOS Action app extension with minimal UI. Basically it would just show a progress indicator until the action completed. I just want to be able to animate the view so that it slides down from the top & then slides back up when the action has completed. If anyone is familiar with Instapaper’s Share extension, then that’s the kind of basic UI I’m looking for.

The problem is that when I try to duplicate this functionality - I just have a small `UIView` that animates down from the top - I get a black background behind my view. I can’t figure out how to make that background transparent so that the stuff behind my view is still visible. Does anyone know how to do this?

As a starting point I’m just using the default Action Extension template that’s created by Xcode...

1. Create a new iOS app project in Xcode.
2. Add a new target -> Action Extension.
3. In the `ActionViewController.m` file add a `viewWillAppear` method to animate the view (using a 1 second animation so that the black background is easily seen):

Code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect currFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = currFrame;

    newFrame.origin.y -= newFrame.size.height;
    self.view.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = currFrame;
    }];
}
```

When this is run the view is animated sliding down from the top. However rather than seeing the UI of the calling App all you see is a black background.

I’ve tried a number of things - changing the `modalPresentationStyle` (doesn’t seem to do anything), setting the entire view to hidden (this just makes the whole screen black), etc.

For reference this is using iOS 9.3.2 and Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Have you tried with the storyboard?

Comment: @RomOne, tried what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I mean have you tried without animations at all, and by using the storyboard to add your subviews to the extension controller?

Comment: With or without animations doesn’t make a difference. Anything behind my main view is black. If I set the background of my main view to transparent the result is black. I’m still not sure what you mean regarding using the storyboard to add subviews. If you create an app extension using my instructions above it will create a storyboard. Adding subviews to that storyboard doesn’t make a difference. Nothing I’ve tried so far will allow the calling app’s UI to show behind the UI of my main view. Anything “behind” my main view always renders black.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html)

> In iOS, an Action extension:
>
> - Helps users view the current document in a different way
> - **Always appears in an action sheet or full-screen modal view**
> - Receives selected content only if explicitly provided by the host app

The fact that the Action extension always appear in a full-screen view on an iPhone might mean that there's no way of having a transparent background.

I am certain that a Share extension can be animated (I've done it myself) how you want it and have a transparent background. That's why Instapaper's **Share** extension works nicely.

Comment: I think you’re on to something here. Changing the extension from an Action extension to a Share extension keeps the calling app UI visible underneath my UI. I thought that action sheets didn’t need to be full-screen? Maybe that’s wrong though.

Comment: To me an action sheet is the .ActionSheet style of UIAlertController. I may be wrong here, however everything indicates that there's no way to have a custom view with UI underneath. I've looked at "top 11 iOS Action extensions"(http://www.imore.com/amazing-action-extensions-iphone) and all of them were fullscreen.

Comment: It looks like this is the right answer. Using a Share extension allows the calling app’s UI to remain visible. Doing nothing but changing the extension type from Share (`com.apple.share-services`) to Action (`com.apple.ui-services`) results in a black background.

Answer (score 1):

*You are facing two problems:*

**1**. When you present a view controller, the default behavior is the controller is full screen context. That is the reason you see a black screen.

**2**. You are trying to change **self.view.frame** when the controller is presented on full screen.

**Yet there is a way to achieve this kind of behavior you are looking for, in one of three ways:**

**A**. Specify "**modalPresentationStyle**" to "**UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext**" and set the presenting controller to "**definesPresentationContext**".
That way, when you present the controller, the presenting controller will be behind the presented controller.

And insted of changing **self.view.frame** you will set  **self.view** background color to clear, and add a subview and use it as a background view:

```
//Presenting view controller:

-(void) presentPopUpViewController {
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES; //self is presenting view controller
    self.presentedVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:self.presentedVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}

//Presented view controller:

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect currFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = currFrame;
    newFrame.origin.y -= newFrame.size.height;

    self.myBackroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.myBackroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.myBackroundView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myBackroundView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.myBackroundView.frame = self.view.frame;
    }];
}
```

**B**. Add the presented view controller as a Child view controller. that way the life cycle stays the same, but you can add I'ts view as a subview, and change I'ts frame.

//Presenting view controller:

```
-(void) presentChildViewController {
    [self addChildViewController:self.presentedVC];
    [self.view addSubview:self.presentedVC.view];
    [self.presentedVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

//Presented view controller:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGRect currFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = currFrame;

    newFrame.origin.y -= newFrame.size.height;
    self.view.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = currFrame;
    }];
}
```

**C**. Don't use UIViewController, use UIView. Use a "Decorator" object, that you pass it the ViewController you would like the view to disaply on, and the "Decorator" will add the view as subview, and deal with the animation. No need for an example for this scenario.

Comment: I tried **A** but this doesn’t work. For starters as an App Extension I don’t have control over the presenting controller. I did try accessing the `parentViewController` and `presentingViewController` so that I could enable the `definesPresentationContext` but that doesn’t seem to do anything. And changing the background color to clear doesn’t let the calling app show through, it just results in black.

Comment: **B** and **C** won’t work either as an App Extension has no control over how the view controller is presented. The entry point for an App Extension is that you provide a View Controller. How and when that view controller is presented is out of your control as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Cutterpillow I didn't understand this is the first view controller that is presented at the extention.. What you are looking for is not possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to start animations when your view hasn't yet appeared. Can you, please, try the same code in viewDidAppear.
Also animating main view controller's view will make underlying layers visible, so you've got to use another view on top of view controller's main view, like this:

```
UIView *progressView = [[UIView alloc] init];
progressView.frame = self.view.bounds;
progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubView:progressView];
```

Comment: Doesn’t make a difference. Same behavior as before.

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't noticed, that you are animating main view of the view controller. You should create another view upon this, like this:

    UIView *progressView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    progressView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubView:progressView];

and then you can perform these animations

Comment: All this lets me do is put another view on top of my view controller’s view (main view). So the new view will appear on top of the main view. However, I still can’t show what’s behind the main view - i.e. the content of the app that launched my extension. If I make the main view transparent or hidden then all it shows is a black background with the new view on top of that.

Comment: Once controller is presented, underlying hierarchy will be covered. There are 3 options:


1. You might want to use container view to move topmost controller. Main controller will be still visible.


2. Insert topmost controller's view on top of main controller view without using storyboards.


3. Simply use view on top of the main controller, not adding progress controller


Which solution do you prefer?