# Action Extension with UI without covering whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, ios-extensions

I am currently trying trying to implement an Action Extension that transforms content on a Safari web page through Google's Translation API.

My issue is that I would like to display some UI on the screen without covering the whole screen, but no matter what I do that doesn't seem to work.

I have tried the following:

- Setting this in the info.plist

  ```
  <key>NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation</key>
  <false/>
  ```
- Trying to change the content size in the interface builder to the following

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCSV0.jpg (Uploading images through stack isn't working for some reason)
- Giving the UI a clear background color (always ends up being grey after the presentation is complete)
- Setting the presentation style to be over current context.

Now i have seen a similar question where the accepted response was that it cannot be done due to Apple restrictions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764183/10058854), but I have seen some apps that seem to do it.

For example, iTranslate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ2Qo.jpg

The above 2 images clearly show that they have created an Action Extension and that the added UI is just the bar at the bottom of the web view.

Any help would be much appreciated, and thank you for reading this.

Comment: Like the comments in the accepted answer to your linked question, I was able to use a Share Extension for this effect. This looks to also be what was done in iTranslate, right?

Comment: No, it seems like they are using an Action Extension, because their icon is coming up on the bar with the other Actions, the Share Extensions are on the bar above (check the second imgur link, but I will try to reupload the images through stack). 

The issue isn't that I just want the layout, the Action Extension allows you to alter content on Safari, the Share extension allows you to share content with your app. So if i could use the Share extension for my purpose I probably would have gone with that.